# Data extraction in R

Tags: r, dataset, data-analysis

I have a data set *data* with structure as

```
'data.frame':   153 obs. of  6 variables:
$ Ozone  : int  41 36 12 18 NA 28 23 19 8 NA ...
$ Solar.R: int  190 118 149 313 NA NA 299 99 19 194 ...
$ Wind   : num  7.4 8 12.6 11.5 14.3 14.9 8.6 13.8 20.1 8.6 ...
$ Temp   : int  67 72 74 62 56 66 65 59 61 69 ...
$ Month  : int  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
$ Day    : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
```

Now when  want to remove NA from the column *Ozone* the following way is showing me an error :

```
mean(data["Ozone"], na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(data["Ozone"], na.rm = TRUE) :
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

How should I remove NA in the above problem?

Comment: did you forget a comma inside the brakets? `mean(data[, "Ozone"], na.rm = TRUE)`

Comment: You have to provide us with your particular dataset, otherwise we are just guessing as to what is going wrong.

Comment: @PaulHiemstra I have given it. I have provided the str(_data_) which contains the initial values.

Comment: The `str` of the data is not the real data itself. Have a look at `dput` to provide us with a version of the data that we can paste into R.

Comment: I tried dput. It gives a large output which I cannot paste here. Any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot a comma when subseting, just include that missing comma and it'll work like a charm

```
> mean(data[, "Ozone"], na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 42.12931
```

I'm assuming you are working with `airquality` dataset.

Note that double brakets (without comma) also works

```
> mean(data[["Ozone"]], na.rm = TRUE)
[1] 42.12931
```

Take a look at [`?Extract`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html) for further details on subseting.